# What causes "/usr/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared" and how do I fix it

Tags: linux, makefile

I ran across this error while trying to compile the NMR software modelfree4.20 for Linux. The distribution comes with a MakeFile, and so I type "make" in the modelfree folder to try and compile it, and after it writes a few files I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'modelfree4' failed
make: *** [modelfree4] Error 1
```

I have no idea what "-f may not be used without -shared" means or what it is trying to tell me to fix? I don't see anything with a -f or -shared in the MakeFile when I open it up, and I didn't specify any options when I ran "make."

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think I could see 2 possibilities.

1. If the Makefile is generated by a configure script, you may need to run it again.  You may have picked up a bad Makefile due to misconfiguration.  Possibly you need to run the autotools to generate the configure script again.
2. It's possible that there is some system- or session-specific `LDFLAGS` environment variable interfering with linking.  Try `unset LDFLAGS`?

Comment: If it is not `./configure`, it could be needing `cmake` to generate a environment-specific `Makefile`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys! The issue turned out to be that the Makefile for the Linux build actually came with both the Linux and Mac commands activated at the top of the script. Commenting out the Mac commands ended up fixing the issue. I am pretty sure rebuilding the Makefile from scratch would have fixed it too, but thankfully I didn't have to go that far.

Comment: same problem for me (building gpac/mp4box) meant I had to pass in the appropriate cross compile sdl-config so it didn't use the (mac specific) default sdl-config...